# SQL Server: Wiping data from a column that has a unique key constraint

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, obfuscation

I have a column of email addresses that I need to delete (for privacy reasons) but I can't simply set an empty string to that each row because there's a unique key constraint on that column.

**What's the easiest way of wiping data from the email address column without deleting the unique key constraint?**

Keep in mind, the table has a composite primary key of 2 columns (let's call these two columns `CK1` and `CK2`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just replace them with something random?

```
UPDATE [YourTable]
   SET [Email] = REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(36), NEWID()), '-', '') + '@fake.com'
```

That will give you something like:

```
3931BB9646304A949D9F4EBA81E9E798@fake.com
```

Or if your table has an identity column, plug that inherently unique value into a new fake e-mail address:

```
UPDATE [YourTable]
   SET [Email] = 'email' + CONVERT(varchar(20), [Id]) + '@fake.com'
```

Or *disable* the constraint (without deleting it) before clearing out the column:

```
ALTER INDEX [YourUniqueIndexName] ON [YourTable] DISABLE;
```

Although that last one might alter the behavior of any application(s) writing to that table.

Comment: Excellent. My original solution was much more complicated than this one statement solution. Thanks! I would mark this as an answer but SO is preventing me to do so at the moment. I'll come back at a later time and mark this as an answer.

Comment: @burnt1ce: No problem. I added a couple of other options as well.

Comment: I've had to scrub production data for dev databases before, and it is worth noting that you removed the previous email address *but you still have a possibly valid email address remaining*.  You might want to put an underscore in the domain part of the email address so it could never arrive at a valid address.